# RSpec - How to get a better error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am used to PHPUnit, so I found RSpec to be inferior when it comes to showing what has gone wrong, where and why.

For example, in PHPUnit, I can get the stack trace when an exception is raised (and even with -b option in RSpec, all I can get is the stack trace of RSpec exceptions, and not Rails's)

Also, when some error occurs, it shows you the **ACTUAL** value and the **EXPECTED** value.

Those two features I'd like to achieve in RSpec. Getting a detailed error message that includes the stack trace, in case of an Exception of Ruby or of Rails, and to know what was the actual value.

Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please, show your test and console output you get.

Comment: Actually, I was expecting a stack trace because of a violation of validates presence of, but I was calling valid? while save! is the method which throws an exception. I don't believe I was that distracted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run

```
rspec --help
```

you will see all the options you can pass (or configure via `RSpec.configure`) to the runner. One of the will force RSpec to show the entire backtrace

```
-b, --backtrace                  Enable full backtrace.
```

You can also configure the [excluded/included](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/configuration/excluding-lines-from-the-backtrace) lines to control how deep you want the backtrace to go.

As for the actuals vs expected value, this is supported by default in RSpec. See for example

[image]

For custom-defined objects, it also print out a diff.